# unable to login into weblogic console

Tags: weblogic

I'm weblogic newbie, trying to abandon it ASAP, but that's not possible for now, so I have to resolve this. Maybe following is completely normal and trivial. I don't know. Please advice.

I had working weblogic 12.1.3 on 2 PCs for months. But suddenly, I cannot log into admin console on neither of them. I enter username/pass from password store, and it's not accepted. While at the same time intellij idea successfully logs in and deploys app using same pass. OK, fair enough, we reset pass, using:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/reset-the-adminserver-password-in-weblogic-11g-and-12c

and update password in intellij settings. Good. Intellij idea is in again, I cannot login. Nothing in logs, neither application, nor server logs.

I cannot login regardless if I start weblogic via intellij run configuration of from bash.

OK, lets try reinstall weblogic. No change.

Weblogic is up and running, app deployed to it, and is responsive. When accessing console URL, it gets printed, that app is being deployed, but I still cannot access it. Cleared caches/cooking etc. nothing. No logs, no error response. Nothing.

Responses to "failed"(?) login on urls j_security_check, console and console/ are http status 302 (moved temporarily). Not sure if it's ok or not, well say I'd expect 401/403, but maybe 302 is valid weblogic response for denied authentication. I don't know.

Any idea?

Comment: Try with other browser

Comment: OK. That's a little bit embarrassing. I did not try that, thinking, that clearing all session/cookies data must be enough. So I tried in firefox instead of chrome and it worked. What the hell. What do you think it could be the cause??

Comment: Can be something stored in to the browser. You can check for webstorage (or whatever was named this in browser) :)

Comment: I'll  try to investigate/delete chrome data altogether. But it's weird that deleting all browsing data did not help and that it happened on both pcs. Anyways, thanks for saving me!

Comment: You are welcome. Will add it as answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is to check [web storage](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp) and try to clear it. But the most clear way is to use different browser. Or use your current browser in private mode. Also in firefox you can create different profile and use it for this specific purposo.

Comment: OK, I know the cause. If you are using 2 different versions of weblogic, in my case 12.2.1 and 12.1.3, these two will ruin local storage for each other and you won't be able to log into weblogic console. Weblogic successfully does this repeatedly and reliably both for chrome and firefox. So if you cannot login into weblogic with correct user/pass, you have to clear local storage.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happened to me both on WebLogic 12 and 14.
My first attempt was to clear browsers cache but the issue was remaining.
Then, I deleted the content of the both tmp and cache folders of AdminServer and eventually I managed to login admin console as suggested by [MartinMucha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1534084/martin-mucha) in comment section of previous answer.

The image below illustrates which folders you should empty in case you couldn't figure out.

[image]